# Turn data in cells into notes.

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, cells

I am trying to take the data of a cell and turn it into a note that then can be attached to a cell in a different spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J0M27DXFvBaEQVI-3vLeFST3LuFxRsmxTes7mQ-v7wU/edit?usp=sharing

In this spreadsheet under "Form Responses" I am aiming to collect data using a Google Form and then categorize and neatly organize it into "English Text Errors" and "Korean Text Errors." I have done this successful but my next goal is to take Additional Comments and Screenshots that the users submit and turn the entered data into a note. I then want to attach the note to the appropriate cell.

For example: 
"QUEST_LV_0100_20150317_000012 Soldier Bag." is submitted by a user in my Google Form. If the user decides to add Additional Comments or Screenshots for that submission, I then want to take the data from that column and turn the data into a note that can then be attached to the appropriate cell in the sheet "English Text Errors." This will make it so when the cell categorizes "QUEST_LV_0100_20150317_000012 Soldier Bag." it will then have a note attached to that cell with the Additional Comments and Screenshots that the user has added. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is pretty simple. There is a function called

```
setNote()
```

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNote(String))

This allows you to set the note from an app script.  From the documentation:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
cell.setNote("This is a note");
```